# Biber/BibLaTeX - How to insert a small-space inside \parencite's-[post]-bracket automatically? Example: (cf. Doe, 1998, page <toobigspace> 25)

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, harvard-style

**Imagine an ordinary *Harvard-citation*-style by using the `\parencite`-function:**

The application in it's initial state...

`\parencite[pre][post]{authorID}`

... in practice, will be used like this...

`\parencite[cf.][p. 25]{Doe}`

... and creates a result like this:

*(cf. Doe, 1998, p. 25)*

---

Is it possible to reduce the space between the pagesymbol `p.` inside the [post]-bracket and the pagenumber `25` (which is also positioned inside the same bracket)? Probably most people easily insert a space by putting the space-key on their keyboard.

Unfortunately, this big space is looking really unaesthetic I think...

---

**One (worse) option would be to cite like:**

`\parencite[cf.][p.\addnbthinspace 25]{Doe}`

**One other (worse) option would also be to cite like:**

`\parencite[cf.][p.{\,}25]{Doe}`

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
% ==== PREAMBEL =============================================================

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[
            backend=biber,
            citestyle=numeric,
            style=authoryear,
            natbib=true,
        ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% ==== BIBLIOGRAPHY ========================================================

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 

    @book{Doe,
        author = {Doe, Jon},
        title = {How to cite a literature-entry in a beautiful way},
        date = {1998},
    }

\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname} 

% ==== DOCUMENT ============================================================

\begin{document}

\chapter{For the friends of typography}

    For generating the following citations, the \textbackslash parencite-function was used:\\
    \textbackslash parencite[cf.][p. 25]$\{Doe\}$.

    \bigskip    

    This is a text with an ugly look because of the big space between the letter \textbf{p.}\\
    and the \textbf{pagenumber} \parencite[cf.][p. 25]{Doe}.

    \bigskip

    This is a text with a beautiful look because of the small space between the letter \textbf{p.}\\
    and the \textbf{pagenumber} \parencite[cf.][p.{\,}25]{Doe}.

    \bigskip

    This is a text with a beautiful look because of the small space between the letter \textbf{p.}\\
    and the \textbf{pagenumber} \parencite[cf.][p.\addnbthinspace 25]{Doe}.

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the initial state:**

[image]

---

**Screenshot of the final (desired) state:**

[image]

---

**Final question:**

Is there any option to set this space automatically to a smaller distance (e.g. `\addnbthinspace`) without putting code inside the input-fields of the `\parencite`-command? This would really be better for the cleanliness of the source-code (as well as an acceleration of the citing-process)...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you do not add the page prefix yourself, but let `biblatex` handle it as in `\parencite[cf.][25]{Doe}`, I'm sure something can be cooked up to insert thin spaces ... I'll investigate.

Comment: BTW it is quite odd that you issue `citestyle=numeric,` and then overwrite this just a line later with `style=authoryear`. In your current set-up the line `citestyle=numeric,` has no effect and just adds confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you let `biblatex` handle pagination on its own, what you want is very easy. Postnotes containing numbers (and a few other special symbols) are automatically recognised as page (ranges) and formatted as such by `biblatex`.

So it is a good idea to drop the page prefix entirely when citing, as in

```
\parencite[24]{worman} and \parencite[cf.][17--19]{geer}
```

`biblatex` then automatically adds the required "p." or "pp." in case of more than one page. Plus, this will make your code even cleaner.

By default the space between the page prefix and the number is a non-breaking space, but we can easily make that a thin space with

```
\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{\addnbthinspace}
```

See also the [`biblatex` doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 194 in the part about `\mkpageprefix`.

There is also `\sqspace` that controls the space between the *sequentes* mark and the page as in "pp. 14 seq.".

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{\addnbthinspace}

\begin{document}
  \parencite[24]{worman} and \parencite[cf.][17--19]{geer}

  \parencite[p.\addnbthinspace 24]{worman} and \parencite[cf.][pp.\addnbthinspace 17--19]{geer}

  \parencite[p. 24]{worman} and \parencite[cf.][pp. 17--19]{geer}
\end{document}
```

[image]